# .NET XML Serialization with CData tag and Attribute

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, cdata

Ok, I am having a bit of a problem trying to serialize a section of code into XML. I need the XML to come out something like this:

```
<document DataObject="Y">
   <data Attribute="Y"><![CDATA[01/01/2013]]></data>
</document>
```

I can generate the xml fine with the CData tag but I cannot figure out the Attribute on the element.

Here is an example of the class:

```
Public Class document
<XmlAttribute()> _
Public AMSDataObject As String = "Y"

Private _Data As DateTime

<XmlIgnore()> _
Public Property VarData
    Get
        Return _Data
    End Get
    Set(value)
        _Data = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Data As XmlCDataSection
    Get
        Return GetCData(Me._Data)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As XmlCDataSection)
        Me._Data = value.Value
    End Set
End Property
Private Function GetCData(ByVal value As String) As XmlCDataSection
    Static doc As New XmlDataDocument()
    Static cdata As XmlCDataSection = doc.CreateCDataSection(value)

    Return (cdata)
End Function
End Class
```

Any suggestions. I am sure there is a easier way to deal with all of this.

Also, here is the serlization class.

```
    Private Sub WriteXMLToFile(ByRef file As AMS_DOC_XML_EXPORT_FILE, ByVal filename As String)
    Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(AMS_DOC_XML_EXPORT_FILE))
    Dim writer As New StreamWriter(filename)

    'Remove Default name spaces
    Dim xns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces
    xns.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty)

    'Remove XML Declaration in front of file
    Dim xmlsettings As New XmlWriterSettings
    xmlsettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True
    xmlsettings.Indent = True


    Using xmlwriter As XmlWriter = xmlwriter.Create(writer, xmlsettings)
        ser.Serialize(xmlwriter, file, xns)
    End Using

    writer.Close()
End Sub
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this to get the attribute, but it's not really any more simple:

```
Public Class document
    <XmlAttribute()> _
    Public AMSDataObject As String = "Y"

    Private _Data As DateTime
    Private _DateData As DateDataElement

    <XmlIgnore()> _
    Public Property VarData As Date
        Get
            Return _Data
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            _Data = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement()>
    Public Property Data As DateDataElement
        Get
            Return New DateDataElement(_Data)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DateDataElement)
            Me._DateData = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class DateDataElement
    <XmlAttribute()>
    Public Attribute As String = "Y"


    Private _date As DateTime

    Sub New()

    End Sub
    Sub New(dateValue As DateTime)
        _date = dateValue
    End Sub

    <XmlText()>
    Public Property Value As XmlNode()
        Get
            Return New XmlNode() {New System.Xml.XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(_date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))}
        End Get
        Set(value As XmlNode())
            _date = CDate(value(0).Value) '??
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```